# Use cases for referencing to a constant variable

Tags: c++

I understand the reference variable concept. It's an alias to the other variable.

```
int varA = 100;
int &varB = varA;
```

Here `varB` is a referring to `varA`, both pointing to same memory location. Changes to one variable reflect in the other.

Question:

1. a) `int &c = 100;`
   What is the meaning of the above statement, and how does it differ from the following?
   b) `int c = 100;`
2. Is there any scenario where we need to use 1(a) rather than 1(b)?

Comment: If you try compiling 1(a), then you'll see why 1(b) is better.

Comment: Does anyone have Visual C++ handy?  Does 1(a) compile there?  If I recall, it allows binding non-const references to temporaries.

Comment: I think the old vc++ compiler did, but they have at least improved upon standards slightly!

Comment: @Pete what, `int& c = 100;`? so what did it do? Did it create a reference to, well, an anonymous int, or was it just jibberish what came out?

Comment: @Whoami Say, stupid question, but why do you have "constant" in your title? Your question doesn't mention anything constant.

Comment: @MrLister: I believe he's referring to the integer constant `100`

Comment: @Mr Lister - who knows?  One day, perhaps archaeologists will find out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All are correct, except this:

```
int &c = 100; //error
```

It will give compilation error both in C++03, and C++11. It is because it attempts to bind *non-const reference* to a temporary object (created out of `100`) which is disallowed.

In C++11, you could do this, however:

```
int && c = 100; //ok
```

It is called rvalue-reference.

You could bind *const reference* to a temporary though (both in C++03, and C++11):

```
int const & c = 100;
```

-

```
int c = 100;
```

It simply defines an object called `c` and initializes it with `100`. No reference here.

Comment: Thanks to all for the reply. you mentioned that we could bind 'const reference to a temporary though', in that case, what is the difference between int const &c = 100; and  const int c=100 ?

Comment: One is reference, other is not. Learn the significance of `&`. Practically, here it doesn't make much difference (at least I can't think of any difference, now).

Comment: Nawaz, may be i put the question differently, which case the const &c =100 can be used ? what i understand is this:  fun(const int &a), fun(123), then the temporary object '123', will not be copied into the stack, rather it is referred from the data segment where '123' is stored?. is my understanding is correct?

Comment: @Whoami: You should rather ask: in which case const-reference is useful. Then one straightforward answer is : when you want to pass an object of type `T`, but you don't want to make it a copy, as copying seems too expensive for objects of this type `T`, then `const reference` is very useful, as it passes the object itself to the function, without making a copy, and at the same it also makes sure that the function cannot modify the argument (i.e the object which you passed). (Note that passing `int` by const-reference doesn't make much sense, as copying an int is too cheap on most machine)

Answer (score 3):

```
 int &c = 100
```

is invalid code, you cannot bind a non-const reference to a temporary.

To make it valid, you need a `const` reference:

```
 const int &c = 100;
```

While,

```
int c = 100
```

is a valid code. It creates a variable named `c` of the type `int` and initializes it with `100`.

Answer (score 2):

1) `int& c = 100;` is illegal, whereas the second one is not.

> I understood the reference variable concept.

If you really understood references, are you expecting that after you do `c = 101` the constant `100` suddenly turns to `101`?

2) No point in answering, since 1) is illegal.

Comment: my mistake. i have not understood completely. :).

Comment: @Whoami think of a reference as an alias. A nickname. When you say `int& c = x`, whenever you write `c`, it's like you're writing `x`. That wouldn't make sense for a non-const reference to a constant - `int& c = 100`, because you can write `c = 101`, which *would* translate to `100 = 101`, which obviously doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 2):

```
int& i = 100;
```

Is illegal.

It is legal to say:

```
int const& i = 100;
const int& i = 100; // same as above
```

Not particularly useful in this context, but it needs to work for the purposes of function calls:

```
    void foo(int const& i) { ... }
...
    foo(100);
```